# Different ports docker container ps and docker swarm services

Tags: docker

i have three nodes in a swarm. On each node I have containers running that I can see with docker ps.

When I do docker service ls I see the services run by the swarm. But the ports opened are different ones when I look at the outputs of port description. How can that be?

When the application is running, is the work done by the containers or the services in a swarm?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Leo for your response. So this actually indicates a misconfiguration?what could happen if the containers on the nodes have different ports open than the services running in the swarm?

Comment: how does your service definition look like? If you have online published the port without mapping it, docker will choose a random host port to publish the target port, for each container.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior about of differents ports when publish a port service in swarm is  a normal behavior when use swarm mode routing mesh.
This happen when you publish a port for a service but leave off the published port value. So  If you leave off the published port, a random high-numbered port is bound for each service task. You need to inspect the task to determine the port

```
 $ docker service create \
  --name <SERVICE-NAME> \
  --publish published=<PUBLISHED-PORT>,target=<CONTAINER-PORT> \
```

For example, the following command publishes port 80 in the nginx container to port 8080 for any node in the swarm

```
  $docker service create \
  --name my-web \
  --publish published=8080,target=80 \
  --replicas 2 \
  nginx
```

In this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#publish-a-port-for-a-service) you will find the information about this behavior.

When you apply a change via a yaml file at your current configuration, this action will  overwritten the current settings, with the new configuration from your new yaml file, so please take your precautions, like a backup from your current configuration before to apply any change.

Comment: Thanks for the helping answers. If the container images itself have already exposed ports, will the port settings in a service yml overwrite or add to the original image settings?